# Strange Create-React-App Heroku Error - Cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, build

So I have been struggling with this issue for some days now, trying almost every forum suggestion that I have come across. Basically I have set up a backend server in order to allow myself to send emails through node. The strange thing is, it works perfectly on my local machine, and it even builds and deploys perfectly when I push to Heroku. But still, I am just prompted with 'Cannot GET /'.

This is my file structure:

```
PROJETNAME
- client
     ^--
        ^-- build
        ^-- node_modules
        ^-- public
        ^-- src
- node_modules
- .gitignore
- package.lock.json
- package.json
- server.js
```

This is my package.json in the root (backend) folder:

```
{
  "name": "sendemail",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "client/node_modules"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.9.x"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "heroku",
    "create-react-app",
    "react"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client":"npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev":"concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "ANDY",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.5",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5"
  }
}
```

And this is my server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.post('/api/form', (req, res) => {

    nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
        const htmlEmail = `
        <h3>Contact Details</h3>
        <ul>
        <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
        <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Message</h3>
        <p>${req.body.message}</p>
        `;

        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
            port: 587,
            auth: {
                user: 'config',
                pass: 'config'
            }
        });

        let mailOptions = {
            from: 'config',
            to: 'config',
            replyTo: 'config',
            subject: 'New message',
            text: req.body.message,
            html: htmlEmail
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
            if(err){
                return console.log(err);
            }

            console.log('Message sent: %s', info.message);
            console.log('Message URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
        });
    });

});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + PORT);
});
```

Here is my package.json in the client folder:

```
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "email-validator": "^1.1.1",
    "firebase": "^4.10.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-s-alert": "^1.4.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

I will also include some Heroku logs, so this is from the console upon visit with all of the configurations above in place:

```
2018-05-31T17:05:30.745029+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-05-31T17:05:33.349990+00:00 app[web.1]: Server listening on port 52364
2018-05-31T17:05:33.029353+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-05-31T17:05:33.029370+00:00 app[web.1]: > sendemail@1.0.0 start /app
2018-05-31T17:05:33.029372+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2018-05-31T17:05:33.029374+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-05-31T17:05:34.589991+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-05-31T17:05:36.032333+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=tranquil-ravine-15017.herokuapp.com request_id=7c7aa9a7-e1d9-429f-9122-ea84040e7627 fwd="46.9.122.184" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=404 bytes=383 protocol=https
2018-05-31T17:11:15.097815+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=tranquil-ravine-15017.herokuapp.com request_id=0df69ac3-e087-4b7a-a13a-84b14937c03b fwd="46.9.122.184" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=383 protocol=https
```

So as you can see here, no significant errors with the starting of the server. Lastly, I'll include the last build (upload to Heroku) as well:

```
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 369 bytes | 369.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  8.9.x
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 8.9.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 8.9.4...
remote:        Using default npm version: 5.6.0
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (package.json):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - client/node_modules (exists - skipping)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        up to date in 3.189s
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:        
remote:        > website@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_83074ef79a0ec69232c64e8b290c1953
remote:        > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > grpc@1.10.1 install /tmp/build_83074ef79a0ec69232c64e8b290c1953/client/node_modules/grpc
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
remote:        
remote:        [grpc] Success: "/tmp/build_83074ef79a0ec69232c64e8b290c1953/client/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" is installed via remote
remote:        
remote:        > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /tmp/build_83074ef79a0ec69232c64e8b290c1953/client/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
remote:        > node lib/post_install.js
remote:        
remote:        added 305 packages, removed 220 packages and updated 1092 packages in 56.689s
remote:        
remote:        > website@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_83074ef79a0ec69232c64e8b290c1953/client
remote:        > react-scripts build
remote:        
remote:        Creating an optimized production build...
remote:        Compiled with warnings.
remote:        
remote:        ./src/components/Admin-Panel-Edit-News.js
remote:        Line 2:    'ReactDOM' is defined but never used                                                                       no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 3:    'Table' is defined but never used                                                                          no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 3:    'Checkbox' is defined but never used                                                                       no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 3:    'Modal' is defined but never used                                                                          no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 3:    'Popup' is defined but never used                                                                          no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 4:    'BrowserRouter' is defined but never used                                                                  no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 4:    'Route' is defined but never used                                                                          no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 4:    'Switch' is defined but never used                                                                         no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 4:    'Link' is defined but never used                                                                           no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 4:    'NavLink' is defined but never used                                                                        no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 6:    'database' is defined but never used                                                                       no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 24:   Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()                                                               react/no-direct-mutation-state
remote:        Line 82:   Unexpected string concatenation of literals                                                                no-useless-concat
remote:        Line 157:  Unexpected string concatenation of literals                                                                no-useless-concat
remote:        Line 328:  'open' is assigned a value but never used                                                                  no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 328:  'size' is assigned a value but never used                                                                  no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 344:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
remote:        Line 344:  Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='                                                                        eqeqeq
remote:        
remote:        ./src/components/Admin-Panel-Add-News.js
remote:        Line 2:    'ReactDOM' is defined but never used                                                                       no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 3:    'Table' is defined but never used                                                                          no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 3:    'Checkbox' is defined but never used                                                                       no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 5:    'BrowserRouter' is defined but never used                                                                  no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 5:    'Route' is defined but never used                                                                          no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 5:    'Switch' is defined but never used                                                                         no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 5:    'Link' is defined but never used                                                                           no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 5:    'NavLink' is defined but never used                                                                        no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 96:   Unexpected string concatenation of literals                                                                no-useless-concat
remote:        Line 171:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
remote:        Line 171:  Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='                                                                        eqeqeq
remote:        
remote:        ./src/components/Admin-Header.js
remote:        Line 2:    'ReactDOM' is defined but never used                                                                       no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 4:    'BrowserRouter' is defined but never used                                                                  no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 4:    'Switch' is defined but never used                                                                         no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 4:    'Route' is defined but never used                                                                          no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 5:    'performLogout' is defined but never used                                                                  no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 52:   'allNewMessages' is assigned a value but never used                                                        no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 60:   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                                                                        eqeqeq
remote:        Line 78:   'showMobileMenu' is assigned a value but never used                                                        no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 89:   'mobileMenuVisible' is assigned a value but never used                                                     no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 94:   img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
remote:        Line 96:   img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
remote:        Line 101:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
remote:        Line 102:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
remote:        Line 102:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
remote:        Line 108:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
remote:        Line 109:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
remote:        Line 112:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
remote:        Line 117:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
remote:        Line 118:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
remote:        Line 118:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
remote:        
remote:        ./src/components/Admin-Panel-Messages.js
remote:        Line 2:    'ReactDOM' is defined but never used                  no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 3:    'Image' is defined but never used                     no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 3:    'Dimmer' is defined but never used                    no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 3:    'Segment' is defined but never used                   no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 3:    'Loader' is defined but never used                    no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 94:   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                   eqeqeq
remote:        Line 176:  'canShowMessages' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
remote:        
remote:        ./src/components/Admin-Panel-News.js
remote:        Line 2:    'ReactDOM' is defined but never used       no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 3:    'Loader' is defined but never used         no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 3:    'Segment' is defined but never used        no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 3:    'Dimmer' is defined but never used         no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 3:    'Modal' is defined but never used          no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 129:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='        eqeqeq
remote:        Line 161:  'open' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 161:  'size' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
remote:        
remote:        ./src/Admin-Reset-Password.js
remote:        Line 2:   'ReactDOM' is defined but never used                                                                       no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 3:   'Message' is defined but never used                                                                        no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 5:   'Redirect' is defined but never used                                                                       no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 53:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
remote:        
remote:        ./src/components/Admin-Panel-Welcome.js
remote:        Line 2:   'ReactDOM' is defined but never used       no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 23:  'form' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
remote:        
remote:        ./src/components/Authentication.js
remote:        Line 2:  'ReactDOM' is defined but never used    no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 3:  'withRouter' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
remote:        
remote:        ./src/Admin-News.js
remote:        Line 2:  'ReactDOM' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
remote:        
remote:        ./src/Admin-Edit-News.js
remote:        Line 2:  'ReactDOM' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
remote:        
remote:        ./src/Admin-Read-Message.js
remote:        Line 2:  'ReactDOM' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
remote:        
remote:        ./src/Admin-Messages.js
remote:        Line 2:  'ReactDOM' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
remote:        
remote:        ./src/Admin-Add-News.js
remote:        Line 2:  'ReactDOM' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
remote:        
remote:        ./src/Admin-Welcome.js
remote:        Line 2:  'ReactDOM' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
remote:        
remote:        ./src/components/Admin-Panel-Read-Message.js
remote:        Line 2:  'ReactDOM' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 3:  'Table' is defined but never used     no-unused-vars
remote:        Line 3:  'Checkbox' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
remote:        
remote:        Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
remote:        To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
remote:        
remote:        File sizes after gzip:
remote:        
remote:        265.06 KB (-103 B)  build/static/js/main.34ea30f2.js
remote:        9.36 KB             build/static/css/main.17f72539.css
remote:        
remote:        The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
remote:        You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
remote:        For example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:
remote:        
remote:        "homepage" : "http://myname.github.io/myapp",
remote:        
remote:        The build folder is ready to be deployed.
remote:        You may serve it with a static server:
remote:        
remote:        yarn global add serve
remote:        serve -s build
remote:        
remote:        Find out more about deployment here:
remote:        
remote:        http://bitlylinkhere
remote:        
remote: 
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (package.json):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - client/node_modules
remote: 
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        Skipping because npm 5.6.0 sometimes fails when running 'npm prune' due to a known issue
remote:        https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19356
remote:        
remote:        You can silence this warning by updating to at least npm 5.7.1 in your package.json
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-an-npm-version
remote: 
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 78.9M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v23
remote:        https://myherokuapphere.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
```

As you can see, neither any alarming errors in the build, which ends up - also being uploaded successfully. I have literally gone crazy because of this. What seems to be the problem here? I have promised a friend to intergrate email function in his website, which is supposed to be delivered next week, and I am super stressed out because of this. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ahhh! I think I see the problem lol. You're not serving the index.html file from your express server. paste this code into your server.js file.

```
   if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Exprees will serve up production assets
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  // Express serve up index.html file if it doesn't recognize route
  const path = require('path');
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! This worked and solved the issue! You saved my week!

Comment: my app crashed and says "application error" when this line exist:
`const path = require('path');`

when i remove it, it works